# Why does st_split not work?

Tags: postgis

It seems I am having a problem with ST_Split function. I am trying the following but it does not work. Can anyone spot any problems with the syntax?

```
select ST_Split(
   ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3.164154576738156 55.926335330437809,-3.16323392764116 55.926283382919387)'),
   ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3.16348554978961 55.92654456162947,-3.163507914241407 55.926112217812459)'));
```

I have tried some more SQL (including the examples in the PostGIS documentation) with st_split and it does not seem to work...

Comment: Do you get an error message? "Does not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I forgot to add the error.
ERROR:  function st_split(geometry, geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: select ST_Split(
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[st_split](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Split.html) is a function for PostGIS 2.0 or above. Maybe you are using a previous version of PostGIS

You can check which version of PostGIS are you using with:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

Comment: Yes, I was using 1.4
Thank you for your answer.